# Shopify API actively refusing connection

Tags: c#, shopify

I am trying to build a shopify app using c# so I have created a private app and got all the api key, password, etc but when I try to make a web request to the url, I am receiving the following exception:

*No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it :443*

I was wondering if I am doing anything wrong.

Here is the code I use to call the api:

```
WebRequest request = GetWebRequest(string.Format("https://{0}:{1}@{2}.myshopify.com/admin/products.json", _credentials.Key, _credentials.Password, _credentials.ShopUrl));
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Which should be the correct format:

```
https://apikey:password@hostname/admin/resource.json
```

Another version of calling the url I have tried is

```
WebRequest request = GetWebRequest(string.Format("https://{0}.myshopify.com/admin/products.json", _credentials.ShopUrl));
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_credentials.Key, _credentials.Password);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

But this also doesn't work

Finally, I also tried calling the example url it gives when you create the private app, but that also gets actively refused, yet if I browse to it, I can see the json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the connection was getting refused due to the proxy server